# Missing parameters in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

This SP `"dbo.PM_Add_PM_Plates"` expects this list of parameters as follow

```
 @PM [T_PM_Add_Plates] READONLY,          
 @Amount NUMERIC,            
 @From_Type INT,            
 @From_Partner VARCHAR,            
 @From_CashDrawer CashDrawerNumber=NULL,            
 @To_Type INT,            
 @To_Partner VARCHAR,            
 @To_CashDrawer CashDrawerNumber=NULL,            
 @TransactionName TransactionName,            
 @MovementType INT,            
 @CustomerAccount AccountNumber,            
 @BusinessDate BusinessDate,            
 @Operator OperatorID--,
```

but When i trying to execute this SP from my application
the list of parameters passed to SP shown in SQL Server profiler are as follows

```
 @Amount NUMERIC,            
 @From_Type INT,            
 @From_Partner VARCHAR,            
 @From_CashDrawer CashDrawerNumber=NULL,            
 @To_Type INT,            
 @To_Partner VARCHAR,            
 @To_CashDrawer CashDrawerNumber=NULL,            
 @TransactionName TransactionName,            
 @MovementType INT,            
 @CustomerAccount AccountNumber,            
 @BusinessDate BusinessDate,            
 @Operator OperatorID--,
```

The first parameter in SP `"@PM [T_PM_Add_Plates] READONLY"` is missing
which is a user defined table type.
The application shows no errors and run successfully but data in `"@PM [T_PM_Add_Plates]"` not inserted in DB.
I want to know if there is any restrictions for using user defined table type in SP or any permissions.
Any help please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe show your invocation of the stored procedure?

Comment: dear,
This issue not created in all machines, it's only created on one machine, so i suppose it's not related to invocation of the stored procedure.

Comment: Note: This issue is created with all SP which contains user defined table type.